# authorized_keys -win 10 ssh issue

Tags: windows-10, ssh, ssh-keys

Raspbian Pi- SSH Client

I used:

```
sudo ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/my_key - "Tom Smith@192.168.X.X"
```

which in return asks for a password, which is not the output I want.

I want to use the identity file. I created a key in Raspbian using `ssh keygen`.

`ssh-id-copy` to Windows 10 SSH Server failed, due to `cat/exec` not being recognized.

As a workaround, I created a file in the .ssh folder on Windows 10 SSH Server named "authorized_keys". I stored "my_key" public key in authorized_keys file.

I can not get to SSH Server without using user password. Help please?
authorized_keys -win 10 ssh issue

Comment: Are you an administrator on Windows 10? Which SSH server did you install on Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, my user is Administrator in WIndows 10, but that doesn't matter? The client I am using is Raspbain .  WIndows Version- Build 18362 OpenSHH Server.  Raspbain Buster- OpenSSH Client

Answer (score 12):

When you install OpenSSH as provided by Microsoft, it ships with a default configuration that contains the following:

```
Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

While regular users can use the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file as you’d expect, administrators cannot.

You have two options:

- Remove these options from `sshd_config` in `C:\ProgramData\ssh`, restart the OpenSSH service
- Use the `administrators_authorized_keys` file in `C:\ProgramData\ssh`

I don’t have any special permissions on my `authorized_keys` file.

If something isn’t working, remember to check the Windows Event Viewer. OpenSSH logs to *Applications and Service Logs* → *OpenSSH*. You may have to change the SSH server verbosity to get all the information you need to diagnose problems.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you

Comment: From Windows Event Viewer- sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user Tom Smith 192.168.50.224 port 32599 [preauth]. What would  cause the reset? Permission issue?

Comment: This log message alone is not enough to judge the situation.