# Connect to OpenSSH Server on Windows PowerShell

Tags: ssh, powershell

Following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell

```
# Confirm the Firewall rule is configured. It should be created automatically by setup. Run the following to verify
if (!(Get-NetFirewallRule -Name "OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Name, Enabled)) {
    Write-Output "Firewall Rule 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' does not exist, creating it..."
    New-NetFirewallRule -Name 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22
} else {
    Write-Output "Firewall rule 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' has been created and exists."
}
```

Up to the above point, it is okay.

Facing hurdle on the next step, which is

Connect to OpenSSH Server

Here running this command ssh domain\username@servername:

```
PS> ssh WORKGROUP/Admin@redacted
```

gives this output:

```
 WORKGROUP/Admin@redacted: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Update: This is what I've tried so far, to no avail:

```
PS> ssh redacted@redacted
The authenticity of host 'redacted (redacted)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:[fingerprint].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? YES
Warning: Permanently added 'redacted' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
redacted@redacted's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
redacted@redacted's password:
```

UPDATE2

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-LocalUser -Name "rishi" -Password 
(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "923311" -Force)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ssh rishi@LAPTOP-T6Q9PBVB
rishi@laptop-t6q9pbvb's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
rishi@laptop-t6q9pbvb's password:
```

Comment: When you put the IP address of the server, you can connect?

Comment: Provide the output of “ping servername”

Comment: @YisroelTech  Test-NetConnection runs giving IP address. PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Test-NetConnection


ComputerName           : internetbeacon.msedge.net
RemoteAddress          : 13.107.4.52
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress          : 192.168.0.131
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 37 ms

Comment: You haven’t provided what I asked for. Please don’t use commentary to provide critical information. msedge.net is a Microsoft domain to determine if you have internet access. Trying to ping that domain tell us nothing. Unclear questions are not helpful. **I am done** I won’t be back. Don’t ping me.

Comment: Your username syntax is incorrect. Check again with the article. // In the first place, you do not have a domain, so you can probably drop that part.

Comment: @DanielB  PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $username = "Admin"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $newPassword = "Bhatia@123"  Next, tried this with password Bhatia@123: ssh Admin@DESKTOP-2BGPKMD
Admin@desktop-2bgpkmd's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
Admin@desktop-2bgpkmd's password:

Comment: Screenshot: https://www.canva.com/design/DAF5MJEUDcM/DYkMbFt2e_9b5cxYpd97zQ/edit?utm_content=DAF5MJEUDcM&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of text content. Instead, add the text directly to your question, possible in a code block to preserve formatting. // Is your Windows account maybe linked to a Microsoft account? Do you actually sign in with a password or maybe with a PIN? Have you tried setting up Public Key Authentication yet? (Mind the [admin account specialty](https://superuser.com/a/1510364/219095).)

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-LocalUser -Name "rishi" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "923311" -Force)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ssh rishi@LAPTOP-T6Q9PBVB
rishi@laptop-t6q9pbvb's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
rishi@laptop-t6q9pbvb's password: